# Effects on Slice Logic Ultilization of FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hardware

I am new to FPGA programming. In the design reports, I noticed there was a drop of slice logic ultilization after route, compared to the one after synthesis. Can anyone explain why? Thanks

Comment: The MAP that is ran after your synthesis does many things, one of those is to replace some of your logic with hard IPs in the design plus it optimizes your design where the signal is constant or the outputs that are not used. IF the difference in reported size is large, then you should look into the report files and see what signals/logic has been optimized, if your code works, then this can't be a problem, but if it doesn't, then you should look into your top level connection and drives.